# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FalseNegatives'

Tags: python-2.7, keras

When i try to build my model, i want to give the metrics such as true positives, false positives, precision, recall, true negatives, false negatives. But their arise this error. I just give :

```
METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]
```

the error it occurring is as follows :

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 30, in <module>
    keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TruePositives'
```

the keras version i am using is 2.2.4 and tensorflow is 1.6.0, how come to overcome this problem?? I want those metrics to evaluate my deep learning model

Comment: Keras 2.3.x should have such metrics, 2.2.4 does not.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro actually i want to run  my project in python 2.7, and this keras 2.3.x is not available for python 2.7

Comment: Well that is a bad idea, Python 2.x is end of life, not supported anymore.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Some version of  tools such as joern, Neo4j database server used in my project needs the support of python 2.7, that's why i am using python 2.7